# linear relationship

Tags: regression, linearity

Could the data points fall on the regression line to assume that the relationship is linear, please check the attached photo

what if the scatter plot shows that the relationship is linear but the residual plot and the partial plots show that the relationship is nonlinear

If my independent variable is nonlinear how can I determine the appropriate[image] type of transformation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linearity assumption](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378601/linearity-assumption)

Comment: Try averaging the Y values at each X on the scatterplot and fit those few points. I suspect that the linear regression is working correctly, but visually it might not appear that way because of the many Y values at each X.